# NumberFormatException when setting SimpleDateFormat

Tags: android, datepicker

The date from DateRangePicker displays as: "yyyy-M-d". 
But I want it to display the date as: "yyyy-MM-dd".

I have tried out the following code:

```
@Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth, int yearEnd, int monthOfYearEnd, int dayOfMonthEnd) {

        String selection1 = year + "-" + (monthOfYear+1) + "-" + dayOfMonth;
        String selection2 = yearEnd + "-" + (monthOfYearEnd+1) + "-" + dayOfMonthEnd;

        Long firstDateSelection = Long.parseLong(selection1);
        Long secondDateSelection = Long.parseLong(selection2);

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        Date startDate = new Date(firstDateSelection);
        Date endDate = new Date(secondDateSelection);

        formatter.format(startDate); formatter.format(endDate);
```

But I get NumberFromatException when I run it at "Long firstDateSelection = Long.parseLong(selection1)"?

Help is much appreciated :) 
Thanks!

Comment: selection1 and selection2 have characters like - in the string, so it is an invalid Long so the NumberFormatException

Comment: What do you expect to happen, when you perform `Long.parseLong("2010-10-10")`? What long do you expect to get on output?

Comment: @azizbekian Well when a date like that is picked the output is indeed ”2017-10-10”. It’s just that a month prior to october and a dayofmonth prior to the 10th, I want a zero in front. So instead of 2017-9-1, the output is 2017-09-01.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `NumberFormatException` because "1234-12-23" is not a valid `Long` number and you are trying to convert it to a `Long` here:

`Long firstDateSelection = Long.parseLong(selection1);`

Since you already have the numbers for day, month and year you can simply format it(no need for `SimpleDateFormat`):

```
String dateString = String.format("%1$04d-%2$02d-%3$02d", year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
```

Comment: Simplicity at it's finest yet effective, thank you for a good answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you check Javadoc about parseLong(string)

**Throws**
NumberFormatException
if the string does not contain a parsable long.

As you can see a string with "-" is not a long number and it throws that exception.

If you want to do it correctly you have to create a Calendar, add it the values you are passing by parameters (year, monthOfYear...) with set(...) and then make getTime() to get Date object.

Don't create a Date object directly (new Date...) because its methods setHour, etc. are deprecated.

Once you have that, you will be able to do .format(dateObject).